# laravel9, uploaded images are not displayed?

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-9

/*  i have one balde that i use for uploading the images "createEvent.blade.php" then i try to retrive it in 2 baldes "indexEvent.blade.php" and "events.blade.php" the images stored in "/storage/app/public/img" and i run "php artisan storage:link
" every thing is fine in my localhost the imges uploaded and displayed fine, but when i upload my website to the server it still uploade the imge but not displying it. i try to figur out that but nothing work. any one can help. */

```
the controller i use to store the imges and updated
    <?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    use Carbon\Carbon;
    use App\Models\Event;
    use App\Models\EventAttendies;
    use URL;
    use Session;
    use Redirect;
    use Input;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
    use App\Exports\EventAttendiesExport;


    class EventController extends Controller
    {
        //admin saide
        public function index()
        {
            $data['events'] = Event::orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(20);
            return view('dashboard.admin.indexEvent', $data);
        }
         
      
        public function create()
        {
            return view('dashboard.admin.createEvent');
        }
        

        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
                'date' => 'required',
                'place' => 'required',
                'event_type' => 'required',
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);

            $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/img');
            $event = new Event;
            $event->title = $request->title;
            $event->description = $request->description;
            $event->date = $request->date;
            $event->place = $request->place;
            $event->event_type = $request->event_type;
            $event->image = $path;
            $event->status = $request->status;
            $event->save();
            return redirect()->route('events.index')
                            ->with('success','Event has been created successfully.');
        }
         

        public function show(Event $event)
        {
           return view('dashboard.admin.indexEvent',compact('event'));
        } 
         
       
        public function edit(Event $event)
        {
            return view('dashboard.admin.eventEdit',compact('event'));
        }
        

        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'title' => 'required',
                'description' => 'required',
                'date' => 'required',
                'place' => 'required',
                'event_type' => 'required',
                'status' => 'required',
            ]);
            
            $event = Event::find($id);
            if($request->hasFile('image')){
                $request->validate([
                  'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,png,jpeg,gif,svg|max:2048',
                ]);
                $path = $request->file('image')->store('public/img');
                $event->image = $path;
            }
            $event->title = $request->title;
            $event->description = $request->description;
            $event->date = $request->date;
            $event->place = $request->place;
            $event->event_type = $request->event_type;
            $event->status = $request->status;
            $event->save();
        
            return redirect()->route('events.index')
                            ->with('success','Event updated successfully');
        }
        
      
   // Event Show "events.blade.php" user side
    public function event()
    {
        $data['events'] = Event::orderBy('id','desc')->where('status','1')->get();
        return view('events', $data);
    }


        
       }



here my from from admin side to uploade the images



<form action="{{ route('events.store') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  @csrf
<div class="overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
<div class="px-4 py-5 sm:p-2">
<div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">

<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
<label for="title" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm sm:text-sm">
  </div>
                                  
 <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6">
   <label for="description" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm sm:text-sm">
  </div>
                                  
                            
  <div class="col-span-6">
<label for="place" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Place</label>
<input type="text" name="place" id="place" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border-gray-300 shadow-sm sm:text-sm">
 </div>


<div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
<label for="date" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Date</label>
 <div class="flex absolute inset-y-0 left-0 items-center pl-3 pointer-events-none">
   </div>
<input datepicker="" datepicker-autohide="" name="date" id="date" type="text" class=" border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg  block w-full pl-10 p-2.5  datepicker-input" placeholder="Select date">
</div>


                                  
<input class="hidden" name="event_type" value="Free" id="event_type">

<!---  <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
 <label for="event_type" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Type</label>

<select id="event_type" name="event_type" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 px-3 shadow-sm focus:outline-none  sm:text-sm">
        <option value="free">Free</option>
        <option value="paid">Paid</option>
         </select>
   </div> -->

   <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
   <label for="status" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Status</label>
    <select id="status" name="status" class="mt-1 block w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 px-3 shadow-sm    focus:outline-none     sm:text-sm">
        <option value="1">Active</option>
        <option value="0">Inactive</option>
     </select>
</div>

 <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
<label for="date" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Event Photo</label>
 <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Title">
 </div>



  </div>
    </div>
     </div>                      
      </div>
       </div>
        </div>
         </div>
  <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse sm:px-6">
                               
 <button type="submit" class="inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-red-600 px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-red-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-red-500 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm">Add</button>
                             
  <button type="button" class="mt-3 inline-flex w-full justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white px-4 py-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2   focus:ring-offset-2 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto sm:text-sm" id="close-Addmodal">Cancel</button>

 </form> 




here i retrive the image in admin side


      @foreach ($events as $event)

<tr class="border-b border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100">
   <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left whitespace-nowrap">
       <div class="flex items-center">  
          <span class="font-medium">{{ $event->title }}</span>
        </div>
   </td>
   <td class="py-3 px-6 text-left">
       <div class="flex items-center">
          <span>{{ $event->description }}</span>
        </div>
   </td>
   <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
           <span class="font-medium">{{ $event->date }}</span>
         </div>
    </td>
    <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-center">
      <img class="w-6 h-6 rounded-full border-gray-200 border -m-1 transform hover:scale-125" src="{{ Storage::url($event->image) }}" alt="{{ $event->place }}"/>
        </div>
     </td>
     <td class="py-3 px-6 text-center">
      @if(($event->status)==1)
       <span class="bg-purple-200 text-purple-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Active</span>
     @else
     <span class="bg-red-200 text-red-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Pending</span>
      @endif
 <!--<span class="bg-green-200 text-green-600 py-1 px-3 rounded-full text-xs">Completed</span>-->



 
here i retrive the imge in user side 


      @foreach ($events as $event) 

             <div class="w-full @if($events->count()>=2) md:w-1/2 @endif px-4">
             <div class="bg-white shadow-lg rounded-lg overflow-hidden mb-10">
                   <img class="eventsPic w-full" style="background-image:url({{ Storage::url($event->image) }});"/>
                   <div class="p-8 sm:p-9 md:p-7 xl:p-9 text-center">
                      <h3>
                         <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                            class=" font-semibold text-dark text-xl sm:text-[22px] md:text-xl lg:text-[22px] xl:text-xl 2xl:text-[22px]  mb-2 block hover:text-primary " >
                            {{ $event->title }}
                         </a>
                      </h3>
                      <p class="text-base text-body-color leading-relaxed">
                      {{ $event->description }}
                      </p>
                      <p>{{ ucfirst($event->event_type) }}</p>
                      <p>{{ $event->place }}</p>
                      <p>{{ $event->date }}</p>
                      <a id="Regis" data-event-id="{{$event->id}}" data-title="{{ $event->title }}" data-event-type="{{ $event->event_type }}" 
                         href="javascript:void(0)"
                         class="register-btn inline-block py-2 px-12 border rounded-full text-base text-body-color font-medium hover:border-red-700 hover:bg-red-700 hover:text-white transition">
                      {{__('sniperTrans.Register')}}
                      </a>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>

             @endforeach
```

Comment: the server I deployed on it larvel8

Answer (score 0):

the problem was I deployed it via GitHub and i do not give the permission to write.